Unmatched Route with expo router
I'm building a React Native App with Expo-router. Everything was working fine until I decided to add a login with JWT. I cannot access to my app anymore, i have an Unmatched Route error.
So before i implemented this, I had this basic app :

With the _layout.tsx in the app folder :
const RootLayout = () => {
    return (
        <Stack>
            <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{
                headerShown:false,
            }} />
        </Stack>
    );
};

export default RootLayout;

And the _layout.tsx in the (tabs) folder :
const TabsLayout = () => {
    return (
        <Tabs>
            <Tabs.Screen name="index" options={{
                headerShown:false,
                tabBarShowLabel:false,
                tabBarActiveTintColor:"black",
                tabBarInactiveTintColor:"#b3b3b3",
                tabBarLabel:'Quêtes',
                tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
                    <Ionicons name="medal-outline"  size={30} color={color} />
                ),
            }} />
            <Tabs.Screen name="profil" options={{
                headerShown:false,
                tabBarShowLabel:false,
                tabBarActiveTintColor:"black",
                tabBarInactiveTintColor:"#b3b3b3",
                tabBarLabel:'Profil',
                tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
                    <Ionicons name="person-circle-outline"  size={30} color={color} />
                ),
            }} />
        </Tabs>
    )
}

export default TabsLayout;

So the App started with the index.tsx in (tabs).
Then i added a new folder that container a component for an authentication context in the app folder and i modified the RootLayout component as following :
import { Stack } from "expo-router"
import { AuthProvider, useAuth } from "./context/AuthContext";

const RootLayout = () => {
    return (
        <AuthProvider>
            <LayoutAuth></LayoutAuth>
        </AuthProvider>
    );
};

const LayoutAuth = () => {
    const { authState, onLogout } = useAuth();

    return (
        <Stack>
            { false ? (
                <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{
                    headerShown:false,
                }} />
            ) : (
                <Stack.Screen name="login" options={{
                    headerShown:false,
                }} />
            )}
        </Stack>
    )
}

export default RootLayout;

Here's the AuthContext.tsx :
import axios from "axios";
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';

interface AuthProps {
    authState?: { token:string | null; authenticated: boolean | null };
    onRegister?: (email:string, password:string) => Promise<any>;
    onLogin?: (email:string, password:string) => Promise<any>;
    onLogout?: () => Promise<any>;
}

const TOKEN_KEY = 'my-jwt';
export const API_URL = "http://localhost:5000";
const AuthContext = createContext<AuthProps>({});

export const useAuth = () => {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export const AuthProvider = ({children}:any) => {
    const [authState,setAuthState] = useState<{
        token:string | null;
        authenticated:boolean | null;
    }>({
        token:null,
        authenticated:null
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        const loadToken = async () => {
            const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(TOKEN_KEY);

            if (token) {
                axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
                setAuthState({
                    token: token,
                    authenticated: true
                })
            }
        }

        loadToken();
    }, [])

    const register = async (email:string, password:string) => {
        try {
            return await axios.post(`${API_URL}/users`, {email, password});
        } catch (e) {
            return { error: true, msg: (e as any).response.data.msg };
        }
    };

    const login = async (email:string, password:string) => {
        try {
            const result = await axios.post(`${API_URL}/auth`, {email, password});

            setAuthState({
                token: result.data.token,
                authenticated: true
            });

            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${result.data.token}`;
            await SecureStore.setItemAsync(TOKEN_KEY, result.data.token);

            return result;            
        } catch (e) {
            return { error: true, msg: (e as any).response.data.msg };
        }
    };

    const logout = async () => {
        await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync(TOKEN_KEY);
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = '';
        setAuthState({
            token: null,
            authenticated: false
        });
    }

    const value = {
        onRegister: register,
        onLogin: login,
        onLogout: logout,
        authState
    };
    
    return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
}

When i reloaded expo, the app was displaying the index.tsx but like if there was the RootLayout like this :
const RootLayout = () => {
    return (
        <Stack>
            <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" />
        </Stack>
    );
};

I assumed that this occured because of the index.tsx, so I rename it. After reloading my expo I got my first Unmatched Route. I also tried to add an index.tsx inside the app folder but I don't know what to put inside it to "redirect" to my _layout.tsx.
I tried this :
import { Stack } from 'expo-router';

const index = () => {
  return (
    <Stack>
        <Stack.Screen name='login' />
    </Stack>
  )
}

export default index;

But it just displayed a stack i think with nothing else than index as header title.
I just want my app to start with the _layout in the app folder, how can i do this ?
